# How to make a symmetric gradient in GIMP?

Tags: gimp, gradient

I want to make a simple gradient in GIMP. The left edge and right edge should be white, the middle 100% transparent. The rate of change shouldn't be linear, I want the transparent part to be much wider than the left and right parts, giving the impression of the edges of the picture fading away when placed on a white background.

I went into the Gradient editor, but couldn't figure out how to use it. I could only add new segments by replicating existing ones, and then changing the endpoint colors at one of them also changed the colors of all other replicas.

I also tried opening copies of existing multi-color gradients for editing, such as Abstract 2, but I couldn't figure out how they are made. Whichever segment I selected, the context menu insisted that the end points are red and magenta, even when I was in the middle of a segment transitioning from sandy yellow to green.

I tried looking into the [documentation](http://docs.gimp.org/2.2/en/gimp-gradient-dialog.html), but if the solution is in there, I didn't find it.

Any ideas how I'm supposed to use the editor to get my gradient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Custom Gradients in Gimp

Designing our custom gradients in Gimp (2.8) can be done from the gradients menu (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>).

Here are steps to create a gradient with center transparent, white left, white right sides:

- Create a new gradient [image]
- Choose actions from the right click context menu:

  [image]
- Select *Left Endpoint's Color* **white** and *Right Endpoint's Color* **transparent**:

  [image]
- Select *Replicate Segment...* - choose **2**:

  [image]
- Mark the right segment as active with a mouse click on the bottom bar:

  [image]
- Select *Flip Segment* for Symmetry:

  [image]
- Define *Blending Function for Segment:*

  - left *Spherical (increasing)*
  - right *Spherical (decreasing)*

  or any other setting to meet your needs.
- Adjust segment handles (bottom triangles) with mouse until distribution as desired:

  [image]
- Give the gradient a sensible name (default `Unitled`), save, and done.

Of course other actions on the context menu list will help us to create those gradients we need.

Comment: Thank you very much! I had had trouble realizing what a "selection" is, because the selection bar didn't always react to a click, but now I managed to get it done.

Comment: @RumiP.: yeah - it's quite a bit of mouse-fiddling involved :)